# An SQL query to update a field

Tags: sql, qsqlquery

We have two tables :

```
    parents ( id:int , name:string , large_family:boolean default false)
    children (id:int , name:string , parent_id: foreign key to parents)
```

I need a SQL query to update “large_family” field in parents table to “true” if a parent has more than two children.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: This is something you shouldn't do. As you can always use a simple count query in order to know whether its a largfe family or not, you shouldn't store this information redundantly. Redundancy can always lead to inconsistencies.

Comment: Just a note, tables have _columns_, not _fields_.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
    UPDATE parents
    SET large_family = CASE
                       WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM children WHERE parent_id = parents.id) > 2 THEN 1
                       ELSE 0
                       END
```

Comment: Hi Tita.p Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whenever you have code, make sure to enclose it in a code block. You can also specify the language after the ``` to show code formatting and color coding.

Comment: I think I did put it in a code block but didn't know I can specify the language, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE parents 
SET    large_family = (SELECT CASE 
                                WHEN childcnt > 1 THEN 1 
                                ELSE 0 
                              END 
                       FROM   (SELECT parent_id, 
                                      Count(*) CHILDCNT 
                               FROM   children 
                               WHERE  parents.id = children.parent_id 
                               GROUP  BY parent_id)) 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   children 
               WHERE  parents.id = children.parent_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

it is my experience: for most of update queries I write its select query and then change it to update.this way makes it very easy.

```
update p set large_family="true"
from
parents p
inner join chidren c
on(p.id = c.parent_id)
group by p.parent_id
having count(c.id)>2
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the table `parents` to a query that returns all the `parent_id`s that have more than 2 children:

```
update parents p
inner join (
  select parent_id
  from children
  group by parent_id
  having count(*) > 2
) t on t.parent_id = p.id
set p.large_family = true
```

This syntax works for MySql.